# how to convert json string from jointjs into equivalent SVG string?

Tags: json, svg, jointjs

I am using jointjs for some diagram creaion. There are lots of diagrams, which use a single canvas by jointjs. On invoking each diagram, the corresponding json file gets loaded on the canvas. Now I need to convert this diagram into a SVG file for reporting. 
As I have multiple diagrams, I need SVG files for all the diagrams. I know that there is an API in jointjs that converts the active diagram. canvas into SVG file. But in my case there are more than 1 diagram for which I need to generate SVG on a single click.
So is there a way to convert the json file of each canvas of jointjs into SVG file?

Answer (score 1):

the svg output component appears to be part of the proprietary side of things.

you might find this page from the google group useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jointjs/XhEzwJ-ROMg
the author lays out how to produce an svg.